# Set variable to equal another variable by copying memory content

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have variable a = 100, how can I set variable b to equal variable a by copying the content of a and not just using pointers or any type of reference to a?

To explain better, I have a called function that makes a call to postgres and saves the the cursor return into a variable (cursor_a). The cursor is then returned to the caller. If I close the db connection in the called function, the cursor can no longer be accessed.

Setting cursor_b = cursor_a and returning cursor_b to the caller produces the same error as if I worked with cursor_a directly. Is there a way to save the content of cursor_a into cursor_b and then close the connection and be able to return cursor_b to the caller?

Comment: Perhaps this is explanatory: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-pointer-in-Python-Does-a-pointer-exist-in-Python

Comment: `b = a` is what you're looking for. It binds the name `b` to the same object that `a` is bound to. Check `id(a) == id(b)`.

Comment: @a_guest I tried a simple "=" and that does not work. I expanded my question with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Can you share your code? Usually you shouldn't share cursors between queries.

Comment: @kravb Even if you copied the memory content, how can you expect the second object to work differently than the first, since they are exactly identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cursor is backed by the connection to the DB, it doesn't have data of its own (that's sort of implied by the name, like a mouse cursor, it points at stuff, it isn't the stuff itself). You need to read the data from the cursor *before* closing the DB connection.